Why does /etc/group file not use user IDs?
Looking at the Linux group file I see that it lists group members by name and not by ID. Other files which need to identify users (e.g. shadow file) use the id.
My question is how or why did group end up like this? It seem awkward if the username changes.

At least on Debian (and presumably on most modern Linuxes), changing the username with usermod -l new_username old_username will maintain the supplemental group memberships (= those specified by username in the /etc/group file).
My guess would be that during the early part of the history of Unix, when tools like sudo and useradd/usermod/userdel did not yet exist, editing the password database with vipw (or even directly with vi) used to be the normal way to create users.
That enabled various obsolete practices that should now be avoided, like UID sharing/reuse: even today, you might find some systems with a "backup root account" with UID #0, often named toor for historical reasons.
Before sudo existed, the way to have multiple system administrators without the need to share the root password between them was to give each of them their own admin account: each of those accounts would have UID #0, but would be otherwise distinct, with its own password, group memberships, and home directory.
Likewise, a multi-user application that needs to have multiple administrators might once have been set up with a particular UID that owns the application binaries and system-wide configuration files, and a group for regular users that need access to application's work files. This way the regular users could use the application but not mess it up; the application administrators would have access to the application UID for updating or reconfiguring the application.
Before sudo, such application admin access might have been done by giving each application administrator an alternate account that would share the UID dedicated to the application's use; this was to be used only when write access to the shared parts of the application was needed.
If there are two or more users defined in /etc/passwd as sharing the same UID, each of those usernames can have a distinct primary group, as it is designated by GID on the /etc/passwd line. Having /etc/group also use usernames ensures such users can have distinct supplementary groups too, even though they share an UID. Similar reasoning applies to /etc/shadow too.
Backward compatibility is a major reason why operating systems and operating system families can become long-lived. And so modern Linux systems will still allow setting up arbitrary users with shared UIDs on the off chance that someone might need to rebuild and run some very specialized software package developed in old FORTRAN in the 1980's, that happens to require some users set up in this old way. But generally you should keep UIDs unique to each user unless you absolutely have to do otherwise.
